# Visual studio 2015 property page can not open Visual studio 2010 property

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to make Visual studio 2010 project work on Visual studio 2015(without upgrading it).

But the problem is it does not open proper property page.

[image]

It works very well in Visual studio 2010 IDE. Or if it is upgraded for Visual studio 2015 toolset(v140).

[image]

If I change the 'Platform Toolset' option to Visual studio 2010(v100), it does not work again.

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar issue. See here:
[Missing Properties when opening VS2010 C++ projects with VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023199/missing-properties-when-opening-vs2010-c-projects-with-vs2015?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In my case, it was related to language settings:

- VS2010 german version
- VS2015 english version 
  -> project properties where not there

Switching the language of VS2015 to german solved it for me.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I never imagined it could be language problem. I almost gave up using visual studio 2015 with 2010. Thanks.

Comment: great. same here. :)

Comment: I reported that issue at microsoft and they just confirmed it. So might be fixed in a future update :)