# Missing Properties when opening VS2010 C++ projects with VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 to work with Visual Studio 2010 C++ projects. 
Those projects are not converted and need to stay true 2010 projects.

Compiling works as expected.
However, when I try to modify the project properties I only get Codeanalysis, everything else is missing.

**See here:**
[image]

**In VS2010 it looks as expected:**

[image]

Can reproduce that: every new c++ project I create in VS2010 does not show the properties in VS2015.

Comment: are you looking at project properties or solution properties?

Comment: project properties

Comment: great, why do I get a donvote for this? comment would be nice. I think the problem is described in detail and meanwhile also reproduced on another machine.

Comment: just found out that it worked at one point in time on a colleges machine. but now he's facing the same issue. We think it could have worked while VS2010 was not installed. But unfortunately , projects will not compile without VS2010

Comment: this seems to be similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911073/visual-studio-2015-property-page-can-not-open-visual-studio-2010-property?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the problem is indeed due to language settings.

Settings with issue:

- VS2010 german version
- VS2015 english version

-> project properties missing

**This fixed it:**

- VS2010 german version
- VS2015 switched to german language

-> project properties there

[image]

Unfortunately it is not possible to change language in VS2010 without re-installing. And I don't want to stay with VS2015 in german language :(

**UPDATE:** 
I reported that issue at microsoft and they just confirmed it. So this might be fixed in a future update